# How to use javascript to get input and put it on the page

Tags: javascript

I have the code below to get a date from a user and then put it in a variable but how do I add an event that once the user picks a date to then add it on the screen.

```
<div class="container" >
    <div>
      <h1>Welcome to this site</h1>
      <p>Please select a date below.</p>
      <p>Click Here: <input type="text" name="date" id="datepicker" /><p> 
</div>
<div id='test'>
</div>

<script>
$("#datepicker").datepicker();
$("#datepicker").bind("change", function () {
    $("#test").text($(this).val());
});
</script>
```

The code works this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$("#datepicker").bind("change", function () {
    $("#test").text($(this).val());
});
```

[<kbd>Working Demo on : JS Fiddle</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/gfb77/)

Comment: As mentioned below, as of jQuery 1.7 you should use `on()` instead of `bind()`.

Answer (score 0):

try on onChange event :

```
 var dateSelected ;
$("#datepicker").bind("change",function(){ 

 //.. your code
  dateSelected = document.getElementById('datepicker').value;

});
```

Comment: `.bind()` is outdated.  As of jQuery 1.7, [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) is the preferred method.

Comment: I'm trying to figure it out but what code of mine would I put into the 'your code' part?

Comment: As per you functionality , as this method is  called whenever date is changed .